# Laravel /admin route cannot goto another Routes, always back to /admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization, laravel-admin, laravel-6.2, laravel-route

I have a problem with my *Admin routes*, everytime I was login as **admin**, it always redirect to **/admin**, and I cannot access another routes like **/articles** or **/users**. I can only access route like **/welcome** or **/password/reset**

I have tried to fix my middleware to be like this:

**App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {    
        if ($guard == 'admin' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/articles');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/login/admin', 'Auth\LoginController@showAdminLoginForm');
Route::get('/register/admin', 'Auth\RegisterController@showAdminRegisterForm');

Route::post('/login/admin', 'Auth\LoginController@adminLogin');
Route::post('/register/admin', 'Auth\RegisterController@createAdmin');

Route::get('send-mail', 'MailSend@mailsend');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController')->middleware('Admin');
Route::get('/articles-list', 'UserController@articles')->name('users.articles');
Route::get('/profile', 'UserController@profile')->name('users.profile');

Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::view('/admin', 'admin');
```

**App\Http\HomeController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

**App\Http\UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Article;


use Auth;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');  

    }

    public function index()
    {   
        if(Auth::guard('admin')){
            $users  =User::latest()->paginate(5);
            return view('users.index', compact('users'))
                ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)- 1) * 5);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('users.articles')
                                ->with('danger', "You cannot access it");
        }
    }

    public function articles(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $articles = Article::where('user_id', $user->id)->paginate(5);;
        return view('users.articles', compact('articles'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)- 1) * 5);
    }

    public function profile(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('users.profile', compact('user'));
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {   
            return view('users.show', compact('user'));


    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request,User $user)
    {

        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->update();

        return redirect()->route('users.index')
                        ->with('success', 'Users updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(User $user)
    {   
        $user->delete();
        return redirect()->route('users.index')
                        ->with('success', 'User deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

**ArticleController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Article;
use Auth;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');  

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $articles  =Article::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('articles.index', compact('articles'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)- 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('articles.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $article->title = $request->title;
        $article->description = $request->description;
        $article->user_id = Auth::id();
        $article->save();
        return redirect()->route('articles.index')
                        ->with('success', 'articles created successfully');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Article $article)
    {
        return view('articles.edit', compact('article'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request,Article $article)
    {

        $article->title = $request->title;
        $article->description = $request->description;
        $article->status = $request->status;
        $article->update();

        return redirect()->route('articles.index')
                        ->with('success', 'Articles updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Article $article)
    {   
        $article->delete();
        return redirect()->route('articles.index')
                        ->with('success', 'Article deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

**Config\auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ]
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ]
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

I am expecting that admin can access another routes not just **/admin**.

Comment: Can you show us your controller? Maybe your `ArticleController`. I believe there is something wrong with your middleware (maybe in your constructor).

Comment: `Auth::user() === Auth::guard('admin')` will not be true ever, btw

Comment: is there any sugestion, sir? @lagbox

Comment: nope, just pointing out that that line of code doesn't make sense

Comment: here is my controller, Sir @nmfzone

Comment: you are using multiple guards ... your controller's middleware is only specifying to use `auth` as the middleware (no guard passed) so it uses the default guard which most likely is not `admin`  ... in your code calling `Auth::guard('admin')` isn't "checking something" it is returning a guard instance

Comment: i already change it to Auth::guard('admin') on my user and article controller. but still error @lagbox

Comment: so i need to put Auth::guard('admin')  in my contrusctor?

Comment: the middleware needs to know what guard to check .. you are declaring to use `auth` middleware without passing it a guard parameter so it knows which guard to use, without that parameter it uses the default from the configuration which is most likey `web` ... try  `auth:admin` so it knows to use the `admin` guard

Comment: if it is possible multiple guards need to be checked you can tell `auth` to check multiple guards: `auth:web,admin`

Comment: where should i put the Auth::guard('admin') ? @lagbox

Comment: you don't ... anywhere you only have the statement `Auth::guard('admin')` you can remove it since it is doing nothing for you ... you need to adjust the middleware you are defining on your controllers to use the guard you need   `$this->middleware('auth:admin');` now the `auth` middleware knows to use the `admin` guard

Comment: I'm not sure why, but do you have another customization in another middleware? or maybe you change something in `config/auth.php` ?

Comment: @nmfzone no, i only use multi guard for Auth just like this https://www.siddharthshukla.in/blog/how-to-use-multiple-authentication-guards-in-laravel-6-app/ tutorial. btw i already post my Config/auth.php

Comment: sorry, Sir. but i don't understand what do you mean. can you type it in code and which file i should put on. @lagbox

Comment: the constructor of the controller `public function __construct` where you define the middleware, `$this->middleware(...)`, you need to adjust that as stated above

Comment: thanks a lot, Sir. it works now. @lagbox